# Android IAP get error this version of the application is not configured for billing through google play check the help center

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

**I started with billing library 3.0**

- An aab file with BILLING permission has been published on internal/alpha test
- I added my email for close test
- IAP products are published and their status set to active
- From android studio my debug config has sign the same android keystore with release aab on google play
- Version code and version name same version on internal/alpha test
  After that i run debug app from android studio And get error:
  [this version of the application is not configured for billing through google play check the help center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BASk6.jpg)

  Anybody have solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653863/android-iap-get-error-this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-bill/69750331#69750331
I solved this problem.
Thanks jun liu

Comment: testing on release .apk or signed apk resolved the issues

Answer (score 15):

I have solved this problem by adding my mail to  [license testing](https://play.google.com/console/u/2/developers/7961021795275712855/license-tester)

Comment: You are rockstar man..  Thank you. It helped.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that this may take a while before google billing services acknowledge new test users

Comment: You deserve a loving wife!

Comment: You are the best thank you.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/google-play-store here is the solution
you need to add license testing

Comment: The RevenueCat guide posted actually has some useful information to set up the initial app and Play Store settings in order for purchasing to start working. Upvoted.

Comment: i was getting wired issue.. some playstore account it works fine.. some not..  it shows free/month.. instead of money ,  i was recently updated  billing v4 to v6.. any idea on this

Answer (score 0):

my project is very old，It build base on ant tools
I found ant tools do not merge the AndroidManifest.xml
So I fix this problem by add：

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.play.billingclient.version"
        android:value="4.0.0" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.android.billingclient.api.ProxyBillingActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```